# Kotlin/Micronaut Unexpected error occurred: No bean introspection available for type

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I'm trying to create a @Put endpoint for my Kotlin/Micronaut application and I am getting the error

> Unable to decode request body: Error decoding JSON stream for type
> [request]: Cannot construct instance of `UpdateGeoTargetsRequest` (no
> Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from
> Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source:
> (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]

I tried updating the project and adding @Serdable, but that didn't work. I also tried @JsonSerializable/@JsonDeserializable and that didn't work.

```
data class UpdateGeoTargetsRequest(
    val geoTargets: Array<GeoPoint>
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move past this by adding @Serdable to all data classes that were involved in http request/response and moving the data classes to their own file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34968819)

Comment: @improbable how does this not provide an answer? I was able to fix the issue by adding the `@Serdable` annotation to all related classes.